# String inputs being ignored

Tags: java, string, input

This is a calculator program. When I write it like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int x1 = input.nextInt();
    int x2 = input.nextInt();
    String x3 = input.nextLine();

    if ("+".equals(x3)){
        int r= x1 + x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("-".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 - x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("*".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 * x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("/".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 / x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("%".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 % x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
}
```

The program doesn't wait to take the third input. When I tried to to make another scanner object for the third input alone, the code worked well.
Also when I tried to switch the order by which I take the inputs so that I take the string input first, the code worked well.
can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Is this Java?  Please tag with a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a function that parses a `String` to an `int`. You need to use `input.nextLine()`, pass it to the function along with your `Scanner`, and then use that value. If the String is not a number, it will ask for another input.

```
private static int parseInt(String s, Scanner input) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return parseInt(input.nextLine(), input);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int x1 = parseInt(input.nextLine(), input);
    int x2 = parseInt(input.nextLine(), input);
    String x3 = input.nextLine();

    if ("+".equals(x3)){
        int r= x1 + x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("-".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 - x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("*".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 * x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("/".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 / x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else if ("%".equals(x3)) {
        int r= x1 % x2;
        System.out.println(r);
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `input.nextInt()` is reading only the digits and `input.nextLine()` reads empty string afterwards. Because of that, `x3` is considered to be an empty string and it gives an error at the end.

@Lóránt Viktor Gerber suggestion works well.

Also, I would suggest you make sure that you read the right inputs (you can print out.) and don't trust to the user who will input. Your program will give an `exception` if users give wrong inputs such as `string` or `double` instead of `integer`.